# How to await the completion of eventHandlers before redirect in React

Tags: reactjs, redirect, async-await, event-handling, react-props

I am writing a Messenger Application with Redux-React-Realtime databases. In a `ProfileSearch` page, there are many `MemberCard`. I need to write a particular feature where upon clicking the “message” button on a `MemberCard` while I’m technically on a profile page, I will redirect to the `Messenger` page, and with the `channel_id` that is passed to it via `props`, will load up all attributes related to the `message_room`.

However, I’m not sure how to make this interaction synchronized.

Currently, upon calling the message button, it redirects me to the `Messenger` component before my action in the `MemberCard` gets completely executed. Is there any particular way to await the completion of the eventHandler, get the return value inside some method of the event handler and pass that information to another component and redirecting there? The child component `MemberCard` does not have access to `this.props.history` unlike its parent `ProfileSearch`.

Here's a short snippet to give some context.

**ProfileSearch.js**

```
class ProfileSearch extends Component {



  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    const locals = this.state;
    locals[FILTERED_PROFILES] = [];
    //pass in searchUser
    locals["search"] = "";

  }



  renderProfiles = (profile) => {
    return (
      <MemberCard
        profile_id = {profile[PROFILE_ID]}
        display_name = {profile[PROFILE_PUBLIC_DISPLAY_NAME]}
      />)
  }


  onchange = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {

    
    const { search } = this.state;
    const all_profiles = this.props[REDUX_DATA_ALL_PROFILES];
    const filtered_profiles = all_profiles.filter((profile) => {
      return profile[PROFILE_PUBLIC_DISPLAY_NAME].toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });

    console.log("Printing filtered");
    console.log(filtered_profiles);

    return (
      <div className="flyout">
        <main style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Input
                  label="Search for profile display name"
                  icon="search"
                  onChange={this.onchange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col" />
            </div>
            <div className="profile-row">
              {filtered_profiles.map((profile) => {
                return this.renderProfiles(profile);
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**MemberCard.js**

```
class MemberCard extends Component {
  //console.log(this.props) shows only user, profile_id and display_name
  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();


      //some logic before calling the async function, which does firebase queries
      const channel_id = await select_or_create_message_room_method(channel);
      console.log(`Channel of uid ${channel_id} created`);
      //Passes channel_id to next component and redirect
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error with handleSubmit from MemberCard", error);
    }
  }



  render() {


    return (
      <Card className={"member"}>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={this.handleSubmit} >
            <Link to={{
              pathname: APP_MESSENGER_PATH,
              state: {
                //Just testing out the features
                postalCode: 1,
                hasSubsidy: 2,
                subsidyType: 3,
                age: 4,
                nationality: 5
              }
            }}
            >
              <span style={{ color: "white" }}> Message { display_name } </span>
            </Link>
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    );

  }
}
```

**Messenger.js**

```
class Messenger extends Component {


  //TODO: No need for PropTypes since it uses constructor pattern
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    const locals = this.state;
    locals[MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID] = this.props[MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID];//ideally gets the channel_id from the calling component
  }


  async componentDidMount() {

    console.log("Component did mount happen");


    if (this.state[MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID]) {
      //loads everything related to the active channel
    }


    console.log("Component did mount ended");
  }



  //TODO:most important, intercept here and change to Redux
  //console.log everything  here
  render() {
    //render items
  }
}
```

**Update**

I realised I left out some information which will affect the answer. It's an action that occurs in some child component, so the `props.history` may not be passed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `Link` and use `history.push` at the end of `handleSubmit`

```js
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  try {
    event.preventDefault();

    //some logic before calling the async function, which does firebase queries
    const channel_id = await select_or_create_message_room_method(channel);
    console.log(`Channel of uid ${channel_id} created`);
    //Passes channel_id to next component and redirect
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: APP_MESSENGER_PATH,
      state: {
        //Just testing out the features
        postalCode: 1,
        hasSubsidy: 2,
        subsidyType: 3,
        age: 4,
        nationality: 5,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error with handleSubmit from MemberCard", error);
  }
};
```

To read data in `Messenger` component, do this:

```js
this.props.location.state
```

**Edit** Based on comment...

Your `MemberCard` component ideally should have access to history object as you are attempting to use `Link` over there.

Anyway ... If you want to access history in `MemberCard` component, you have 2 options.

1. Use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) for `MemberCard` component.
2. Use [custom history object](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Router/history-object) and pass it to the `Router`. This way your `MemberCard` will have access to history object.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inconvenience. I have a feeling your answer might work, but I think I have left out some essential context to my problem, which requires you to tweak your answer. Do you mind doing that for me?